# How to correct error message Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: HYT00: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Login timeout expired

Tags: r

I am trying to connect to SQL Server by establishing a connection through R studio but I receive the error mentioned.

I am not sure what is causing this issue, I believe my code is correct.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Servers everywhere tend to disconnect inactive users/programs. Also, I've run into this problem when the server glitched (e.g., under heavy load) or the network glitched. Either way, first `dbDisconnect(con)` (the old connection, just in case) and then re-`con <- dbConnect(...)`. While this doesn't happen all the time for me, in general in programming one needs to be prepared for the connection to need resetting.

Comment: Even on a first-connection-attempt, I've seen this error when the SQL Server is struggling hard with something. This might not be a problem on your end. Contact the DBA(s) and see if they can corroborate this with something they see on their end.